# Pysaprk dataframe write to separate file and filename based on column unique values customerid

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have following dataframe(dfcustomer) after the transformation and calculation. for each customer i would like to write to separate file and filename with customerId
`dfcustomer.write.mode("overwrite").partitionby("customerid").format("parquet")`.
The problem with this if the customer doesn't exist in the today dfcustomer dataframe, the overwrite option will delete the existing customer.
Alternative option tried with this, but it has performance and taking longer time.

```
customers = dfcustomer.select("Customerid").distinct().flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
dfs = [dfcustomer.where(dfcustomer["Customerid"] == customer) for customer in customers]
```

Any better way to achieve this.

```
Customerid  Businessday     balance
C1          09-01-2021      $1000
C1          09-02-2021      $1500
C1          09-03-2021      $2000
C1          09-04-2021      $1800
C1          09-05-2021      $2500
C1          09-06-2021      $1500
C1          09-07-2021      $1000
C1          09-08-2021      $1000
C1          09-09-2021      $1000
C2          09-05-2021      $2000
C2          09-06-2021      $2000
C2          09-07-2021      $2000
C2          09-08-2021      $2000
C2          09-09-2021      $2000
C3          09-03-2021      $3000
C3          09-04-2021      $3000
C3          09-05-2021      $3000
C3          09-06-2021      $3000
C3          09-07-2021      $3000
C3          09-08-2021      $3000
C3          09-09-2021      $3000
C4          09-05-2021      $1500
C4          09-06-2021      $1500
C4          09-07-2021      $1500
C4          09-08-2021      $1500
C4          09-09-2021      $1500
```

Comment: Tell us more about the data. Can you append the incoming dataset, rather than overwriting the previous data?

Comment: The input datasets are customers master data with pervious calendarday balance as one glue catalog table and everyday all the transaction details for each customer as another glue catalog table from s3. after the ETL transformation merge and join and calculation the final dataframe dfcustomer is as mentioned above, write to separate file in s3 for each customer and filename as customerId partition by.

Comment: Append will not work because of the business rule transformation calculation. For example customer1 started transaction from 01-01-2021, will calculate the balance everyday, and if there is any adjustments happen during it history of any transaction date and i need to recalculate and need overwrite. if i do append the history balance will not change.

Comment: So it sounds like if a customer doesn't have transactions on the current day, they're removed from the previous day balance table when you write it out. Is that right? Can you show us how you're processing the current day transactions and then joining them to the balance table?